# What does the white-on-brown number in the top bar linked to the review queues mean?

Tags: support

Can't figure out what this number means. Can you tell me?

[image]

Comment: I thought it was the number of open "Suggested Edits", but your screenshot proves otherwise! This brings me to another related question: How is it decided when to show it and when to hide?

Comment: If you hover over it, the tooltip says "xxx total posts awaiting review". The number will not match what you see in **your** review queues as you may have reviewed some of them already.

Comment: See, I always saw that color as orange, just like the logo. My color perception may be off, which explains the laughter when I get into work...

Answer (score 1):

If you hover over it, the tooltip says "xxx total posts awaiting review".

The number will not match what you see in your review queues as you may have reviewed some of them already.

In addition:

- On [so] the Close Vote queue number is excluded from this count.
- Everything else is included in the count, even if you don't have sufficient privileges to review some items.
- The count is cached.

> As of a few minutes ago, we are replacing the pending suggested edit
>   count in the top bar with the number of pending reviews for diamond
>   moderators and folks with [the "moderation tools" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (i.e.
>   10k users on graduated sites and whatever that level's at on betas):
>
> [image: 10K users ONLY]
>
> We are excluding the Close Vote queue from this on Stack Overflow, and
>   there's a minimum of 10 pending reviews that have to be in the system
>   before the indicator will show up.
>
> It is also cached, so may or may not be very accurate depending on the
>   amount of ongoing activity in /review at any given time.

Source [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/267099)

Comment: Thank you. If you constantly refresh the page, they still do not match up, it's not realistic to assume that half a hundred reviews was cleared during the same second. So... cached? What's the point of caching sum when you are not caching each individual  summand? Basically it means that the top bvar displays outdated wrong information whereas the page itself display different (correct?) information. I'm struggling to understand how this is useful...

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh "The number will not match what you see in your review queues as you may have reviewed some of them already." as noted in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, what does that mean? That the number of items that I review is subtracted from each individual queue but not from the sum of them? This again begs the same question: what sense does it make? (Note: I'm sure there is certain sense in it, it's just that I cannot discern it)

Comment: Say for example the total number is 137 as in your screenshot. That means there are 137 total reviewable items in the review queues. If you have already reviewed some of the 137 items then the numbers you see in each queue won't add up to 137 because there will less than 137 that **you can still review**.